# How to uninstall Linux Mint from a laptop with double OS?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, windows

I have the Linux Mint and Win 8.1 32bit on my laptop. I think this is a simple question. How should I remove the Linux and then install an Ubuntu? The last time I tried, the grub was removed and I couldn't find even the Windows. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do something special to uninstall Linux Mint. Just start regular Ubuntu installation and in 'Installation Type' window select 'Something else'. At the next step remove Linux Mint partitions and use appeared unpartitioned free space to create new partitions for Ubuntu.